# MySQL SELECT query with CASE or IF

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case, where-clause

I have a table with products priorities per market and in case a market is not defined a default priority with market = NULL. For example:

`market - product_id - priority
NULL - 101 - 1
NULL - 201 - 2
NULL - 103 - 3
DE - 101 - 2
DE - 103 - 1
DE - 201 - 3
US - 101 - 1
US - 103 - 2`

I need a query which gives me all product priorities for a given market but in case this market is not defined in the table then the default values with market = null. When I use `WHERE market = 'DE' OR market IS NULL` I get both, the entries for DE and NULL, but how to use the WHERE clause to get only DE if it is configured?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Why are you not using WHERE market='DE', I don't get your exact question

Comment: Put another way, you always want to return all distinct products and their priority, but when a market doesn't have the product defined, you want to use the default product and priority from market.

Comment: I always ask a certain market. For DE the priority is defined. When I use 'ES' for example, the query should return the entries for market = null (the default values). Usually I use `WHERE col = 'xy' OR col IS NULL ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1` but it works only for tables with exactly one row per value 'col'. In this case the number of rows can be different for each market.

Comment: I've tried `WHERE market = 'XY' XOR market IS NULL` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach assuming you want to always return the same master product set...

```
 SELECT coalescce(B.market,A.Market) as Market
         , coalesce(B.product_Id, A.Product_ID) as Product_ID
         , coalesce(B.priority, A.Priority) as Priority
    FROM table A
    LEFT JOIN table B
     on A.Product_ID = B.Product_ID
    and A.Market is null
    WHERE B.Market = 'DE'

market - product_id - priority
DE     - 101        - 2
DE     - 103        - 1
DE     - 201        - 3
```

Since DE exists in table, the coalesce ensures the B table values are returned.

If however a product existed in NULL but not in the market
a NULL market with that product_Id and priority from A would be returned.

such as for market 'US'..

```
NULL - 201 - 2
US   - 101 - 1
US   - 103 - 2
```

Which may or may not be what you're after.  as it returns extra products for a market.

If however, you're after NULL market when no market exists for defined market then a different approach is needed.

The null value is causing some challenges since we can't compare NULL in an equality (`NULL = 'DE'`) doesn't work.  So if we translate the NULL value to one we can compare then this becomes a simple where clause evaluation.  So this ASSUMES '#$' will NEVER appear as a market value.  This is rather hackish though.

TESTED

[SQL FIDDLE ES](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08e28/2)

[SQL FIDDLE US](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08e28/3)

```
Select * 
from table
where coalesce(market,'#$') = 
      case when (Select count(*) 
                 from table 
                 where market = 'ES') > 0 then 'ES' else '#$' end
```

So the cleanest approach I can think of is a procedure which simply first checks the count of 'desired market' if 0 then where clause is null if not 0 then where clause uses 'desired market' value provided.  If not for the null, I wouldn't have to make up a value and it wouldn't feel as hackish.

Comment: This looks almost perfect but for the 'US' market there should be only products and their values for the US market (without the NULL row)

Comment: I've tried a completely different approach. The issue here is we don't know if the value provided is in the list of markets.  So until we know that we know that both markets (null, and desired) have to be considered.  Thus the count to see if it exists followed by some logic to return the correct one based on if the market exists or not.

Comment: The last query works fine for me, thank you very much!